# Xamarin.Forms SwipeView OnClick Event Handler

Tags: xamarin.forms, swipeview

I'm experimenting with the new SwipeView controls in Xamarin forms 4.4, and have been going through the FavFighters example ([Code on Github](https://github.com/jfversluis/FavFighters)) and think it's brilliant.

I'm able to add a Swipe right/left gesture as I wanted, but I can't find out how to add an OnClick event to an item in the list, in a Master/Detail type of project.  I was hoping to use the swipe left/right actions for shortcuts, but want the user to click on the listed item to drill-into it further.

Is there a way of adding an OnClick (or an onSelected) event to the SwipeView items?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely go with `Xamarin.Forms.Effects` which allows you implement different effects with native features.
You can refer this: https://github.com/mrxten/XamEffects it shows how to have tap effect, long tap effect, which will be helpful in your case [you can do that even without installing third party plugin].

Answer (score -2):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF.

[image]

If you want to add the click event for your `SwipeView`. you just add the `GestureRecognizers` in your swipeView like following code.

```
        <SwipeView>
        <SwipeView.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
        </SwipeView.GestureRecognizers>

        <SwipeView.LeftItems>
            <SwipeItems>
                <SwipeItem Text="Favorite"

                   BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                   Invoked="SwipeItem_Invoked" />
                <SwipeItem Text="Delete"

                   BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                   Invoked="SwipeItem_Invoked_1" />
            </SwipeItems>
        </SwipeView.LeftItems>
        <!-- Content -->

        <Grid HeightRequest="60"
         WidthRequest="300"
         BackgroundColor="LightGray">

            <Label Text="Swipe right"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </SwipeView>
```

In the background code.

```
    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1());
    }
```

Comment: Without the delete button - essentially, I want a Tapped event for the SwipeItem.

Comment: @Brett Rigby to achieve tapped event for the SwipeItem , please add the `Invoked="SwipeItem_Invoked" ` in the `SwipeItem `

Comment: Not working.
Two events are triggered when the swipe object is clicked.